# Meaning of "special preserve"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> She regards negotiating process with customers as her special preserve.

Preserve as defined by various dictionaries mean *to save, to reserve* etc but I don't think it relates any how to the meaning conveyed in the above given sentience so what does *special preserve* mean in the above given sentience ?

Comment: What is the source? I suspect the grammar because *process* requires an article (ex: She regards *the* negotiating process...). As for [*preserve*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/preserve), how about "5. *countable noun* - If you say that a job or activity is the preserve of a particular person or group of people, you mean that they are the only ones who take part in it." However I can't say for sure without more context.

Comment: @user3169  This is from an error spotting exercise. You may be right that the article 'the' is missing here.

Answer (score 0):

In this case *preserve* has the following definition:

> [**preserve**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/preserve) (n): *an activity that only one person or a particular type of person does or is responsible for: "Owning racehorses is the **preserve** of the rich"*

I don't really like the use of *preserve* here, but then the entire sentence is ungainly.  "Negotiating process with customers" is, at best, juvenile writing.  I would have said simply "customer negotiation".

> She regarded customer negotiation as her own, personal domain.

Note you don't need "the" here since "customer negotiation" is a kind of a *title* or proper noun for a division of the business, like "Sales" or "Accounting".  It's debatable whether it ought to be capitalized ("Customer Negotiation"), since it's not really a *formal* business unit.

Comment: "Negotiating with customers" sounds better to me. Less ambiguous. "Customer negotiation" could also describe deciding who gets the customers, or physically negotiating around customers, or the manner in which customers' needs are handled.

Comment: @sammygerbil  It's kind of an ugly sentence one way or the other, so I'd prefer a different term altogether.   The challenge is to match it with a word like "preserve" which implies a self-contained area.  That's why I feel "customer negotiation" works better ... but in the end it's just creatively piling manure.